# Identify shading language in Trove

Tags: glsl, hlsl, cg, shading

I'm playing this voxel game named Trove, running it in DirectX, their requirements are DirectX 10 and OpenGL 3.2

The character entity in this game emits light when it gets close to any surfaces (walls, floor, etc). I am assuming that they codded that into these shaders unified files.

I want to put this light on like the smallest value or remove it completely as a personal mod for myself. (the game is very modable, another guy edited these files are moved the glare and the fog, I am interested in doing that too, since a patch came and broke his mod)

So, I was wondering what shading language is that, so that I can look up and learn the right thing to make this work in the end.

This game is free to play on steam.

I've extracted the game files and they have this folder called **shadersunified** and I've uploaded all the content at [indexed shadersunified folder](http://laezaria.com/trove/shader/shadersunified/)

I am completely new to this kind of modding, I have absolutely no knowledge, but I do know programming like C++, C#, Pawn, Java, Javascript.

I need some directions toward what this game uses so that I know what to look into :D . Or if any of you can do these changes, I would love that even more.

Comment: From a quick glance at the source (especially the *.common* files) it would appear that this is a custom shader language (based on HLSL) which is probably run through a custom shader compiler to produce shader programs for the targeted platform.

Answer (score 3):

I can't comment since I don't have enough rep yet.

As UnholySheep said in the comments to your question, looking at the .common files you can find out that this is indeed a custom shader language. Specifically './programs/common/kdefines.common' indicates this.

The file I mentioned defines their custom types and functions as the relevant type/function in either HLSL or GLSL, whichever is being used on the target platform.

Since you say that you're new to this:

If you want to mod the shaders for Trove you will be safe to use the same syntax and style that they've used in their own shaders, however it would be helpful to you to research and have knowledge in both HLSL and GLSL. This is to ensure that your shaders work entirely as you expect when writing them since there is no guarantee that whoever defined this custom language defined it to *exactly* match the specifications of both HLSL and GLSL (depending on the use cases, requirements, etc).

Comment: Thank you for your indications. At least I know what to do now :D